# Преобразование объекта int в list

Tags: python, list, map

Есть цикл в котором из `cache` выбираются значения:

```
  cache = [[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)],
     [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 0)],
     [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1)],
     [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, -1)],
     [(0, 0), (-1, 0), (0, 0)],
     [(0, 0), (-1, 0), (-2, 0)],
     [(0, 0), (-1, 0), (-1, 1)],
     [(0, 0), (-1, 0), (-1, -1)],
     [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)],
     [(0, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 1)],
     [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)],
     [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0)],
     [(0, 0), (0, -1), (1, -1)],
     [(0, 0), (0, -1), (-1, -1)],
     [(0, 0), (0, -1), (0, 0)],
     [(0, 0), (0, -1), (0, -2)]]
```

Сам цикл

```
for x in range (len(cache)):
    for e in range(len(cache[x])):
        q,z = cache[x][e]
        print(q)
```

Как получить из q, получаемых на каждой итерации в цикле, получить список? 
`map(int,str(q))` не получилось применить, тк есть отрицательные q

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос, какой конкретно результат вам нужно получить. Сейчас вопрос звучит так, будто вам целое число нужно превратить в список.

Comment: Добавьте метку языка

Comment: Действительно звучит не верно. Прошу прощения. Уточняю: в результате нужно получить список из всех q, которые получаются в цикле при каждой итерации

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 (j for i in map(lambda x: tuple(zip(*x))[0], cache) for j in i)
```